# why does the custom component run before the page is created in ionic 2?

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I would like to implement a custom component in my ionic project and I followed [this guide](https://www.joshmorony.com/custom-components-in-ionic-2/) to realize it.

On my page, instantiate a variable to pass to my component

```
export class NewSegmentPage {

name: any;

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
this.name = "hello";      
}
```

and in the template

```
...
<ion-content>
  <slider [name]="name"></slider>
</ion-content>
```

Now I create my component

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-range dualKnobs="true" pin="true" [(ngModel)]="structure"></ion-range>
</ion-item>
```

and retrieve the data that I pass to the variable by **@Input**

```
@Input("coordinates") activity;
structure: any = { lower: 33, upper: 60 };

constructor() {
   console.log(this.activity);
}
```

but this.activity variable is undefined.

In addition, in the google console I saw that the component is created before the page and that's why it fails to pass the data. But, How does it behave like that?

Answer (score 0):

The execution is right but I was wrong to retrieve the **this.activity** variable in the constructor. Off of my constructor my variable is instantiated.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
   console.log(this.activity);    
}
```